# Can I log how long resume (un-hibernate) takes?

Tags: scripts, hibernate, startup

This question has been spun off from my question about [hibernate being slow](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2408/where-do-i-even-start-if-hibernate-un-hibernate-is-slow).

I know I can run a script when I resume the computer by putting it in `/etc/acpi/resume.d`, but that will only run it once. What I was hoping for was a "starting wakeup" script and a "finished wakeup" script, so each one would log it's time somewhere and I could see how long resume works.

I figure this is a long shot, since the "starting wakeup" script would have to run really early, so even if it was possible, there might not be a disk to write to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look in `/var/log/syslog` for a general system log, it will contain messages from the kernel about the hibernate process.

The delta from when processes start being frozen to when there are no more kernel log messages (until it starts at *0.0000000* on reboot) is the time your computer took to hibernate.